# Cannot use EF canonical functions

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0 with SQL Server 2008 and C#.

I have declared EF in my web.config as shown below:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
  </buildProviders>
```

But when I try to use EF Canonical's functions such as TruncateTime, etc. I could not find "EntityFunctions" in the Intellisense list and it shows error.  Please see the screenshot below.  Which library do I need to import?  Thanks.

[image]

My Current declaration for libraries are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: Try using System.Linq in class where you have this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`where i.Locked == true`

`where i.DateOfInterview == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)`

You'll need `using System.Data.Objects`.